# How to add adoptable storage on android 6

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

I read an article claiming that on android 6, it is possible to format an SD card as adoptable storage (about time).

I have an ASUS Zenfone, with a PNY 128Gb SD card.  I have used an identical card for some time as external storage, but that's not very useful.

First, in settings -> System ->About indicates that the system is running Android 6.0.1

The article claims Settings -> Storage and USB, that I can click on the device, and it will offer to format as internal storage.  The only option I can see is portable storage, there is no choice for adoptable.  After I format, there are only two choice, eject and format.

How can I get the system to adopt the storage?

I found a video claiming that ASUS disabled the feature, and showing how to use adb and enable it by hand. Before I do this, I want to know if there is any easier way, and if there is any potential problem, including what might happen at the next upgrade.

Last, any idea why ASUS would do something as obnoxious as disabling a major feature like this?

Comment: Asus and other manufacturers disable this because they know, just like Google does, that it is a very poor implementation and since many apps haven't been written to take advantage of it , it is of little real use. The other reason is using an SD card as adopted storage puts a lot of write stress on your SD card, often causing it to fail prematurely, and if it's adopted storage (thus encrypted) it could result in catastrophic data loss because one mis-written or mis-read bit could mean the everything on the card is unrecoverable. It would be wise if the feature itself was removed from Android.

Comment: If you plan on using it as adopted storage, use a high quality, commercial grade microSD card, not the cheap consumer grade stuff (you didn't specify which PNY card so I can't really say if your qualifies or not), and make sure it is FAST, like U3 rated fast, because the write speed is what is important here.

Comment: This would not be an issue if they would let me mount directories as in a normal unix machine.  I don't want encryption, I want to be able to offload all non-essential apps and data to a card.  Oh well.